# Restrict access to a page in Gatsby.js to logged in users

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, gatsby

On my gatsby.js static site, I want to restrict access to my `pages/dashboard` page using client-side authentication.  The plug-in, `gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect` says that I can create a redirect with this...

```
createRedirect({ fromPath: '/old-url', toPath: '/new-url', isPermanent: true });
```

...but I'm not sure where to place that in my code. I'm assuming `gatsby-node.js`, but I'm not sure how.

I want to do something like this,

```
if (user.loggedIn) {
  // redirect to '/dashboard'
} else {
  // redirect to '/'
}
```

This is assuming that the state of `user` is available throughout the site.  Is this possible?

Also, in the `gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect` docs, it states that this plugin should be put last in the array in `gatsby-config.js`.  But I already have `gatsby-plugin-netlify` placed last.  Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is give a **programmatic, non-direct access** to the `/dashboard` page using `navigateTo` in `Link`.

See [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5697) issue.